# Creating relations makes it difficult to edit tables

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

When relations between tables are created it becomes very difficult to edit tables, drop and re-create them. well I decide to leave creating relations for when the job is done and that time its not easy either and later some tables might need modifying again. 
what is the best practice for creating foreign keys, and all other relations?

In big projects that I devide project to several small projects, well sometime in one of the smaller projects I see that I have to make a small change to previous small projects. and this ruins everything.

Comment: Isn't this too opinion-based?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I voted to close as such.

Comment: This is a reason to use a database project and source control, not a reason to do without referential integrity.

Comment: well I want to know which way the professionals do the job and which ways they don't suggest.

Comment: Professionals create the best possible models from the start, knowing that changes to the models tend to ripple through the rest of the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always create relations when I create my initial database structure, and because it is normally (sometimes... once was...) designed properly, the relations don't tend to change.

What you may find eases any changes to the tables is to change one of the options

In `Tools-Options`, choose `Designers - Table and Database Designers` and clear the checkbox marked `Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation`